# Show that if $[III]=\lambda[I]$ for some function $\lambda$ on the surface, then either $K=0$, or the surface is part of sphere.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

> Show that if $[III]=\lambda[I]$ for some function $\lambda$ on the surface, then either $K=0$, or the surface is part of sphere.

Here's what I got:

We know that $[III]-2H[II]+K[I]=0,$  so $2H[II]-K[I]=\lambda[I]$.

Grouping terms, I get $(2H-\lambda)[II]=K[I]$. Here's the part that I'm not sure:

Suppose $\kappa_1,\kappa_2$ are two eigenvalues of map $L$, then the matrix for $L$ can be written as $\begin{pmatrix}\kappa_1&0\\0&\kappa_2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Multiply both side by $[I]^{-1}$, I get:

$(2H-\lambda)[L]^t=K[I]$

which yields:

$(2H-\lambda)\begin{pmatrix}\kappa_1&0\\0&\kappa_2 \end{pmatrix}=K\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\kappa_2 \end{pmatrix}$

Am I doing this right? If so, then wouldn't it be the case that$[L]=[L]^t$ is always true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2H[II]=(\lambda-K)[I]$$

If $H(p)\neq0$ then $p$ is a umbilic point and $K=\dfrac{H^2}{2}>0$.

If $p$ is a umbilic point and $H(p)=0$ then $K=-\lambda<0$ but at an umbilic point $K(p)=k^2\geq0$.